# how i can print text in dot matrix font from c#?

Tags: c#, matrix, printing, fonts, dot-matrix

This code is working great but The code print the text  in simple font but I want to print it in dot matrix font , any code to print it in dot matrix?

```
try
  {

 PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument();

 pd.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = new PaperSize("A4", 827, 1170);

 pd.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(this.pd_PrintPage);

 pd.Print();

}
catch (Exception ex)
  {
MessageBox.Show("پیج کو پرنٹ کرتےوقت ایرر آگیا", ex.ToString());
}
private void pd_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
   {
    e.Graphics.DrawString(textBox1.Text.ToString(), new Font("BroadWay", 18,   
    FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, 14,95);
    e.Graphics.DrawString(textBox2.Text.ToString(), new Font("BroadWay", 18,   FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, 12, 165);
    e.Graphics.DrawString(textBox3.Text.ToString(), new Font("BroadWay", 18, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, 12, 265);
    e.Graphics.DrawString(textBox4.Text.ToString(), new Font("BroadWay", 18, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, 346, 96);
    e.Graphics.DrawString(textBox5.Text.ToString(), new Font("BroadWay", 18, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, 285, 165);
    e.Graphics.DrawString(textBox6.Text.ToString(), new Font("BroadWay", 18, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, 285, 229);
    e.Graphics.DrawString(textBox7.Text.ToString(), new Font("BroadWay", 18, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, 285, 287);
    e.Graphics.DrawString(textBox8.Text.ToString(), new Font("BroadWay", 18, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, 146, 326);
    e.Graphics.DrawString(textBox9.Text.ToString(), new Font("BroadWay", 18, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, 742, 96);
    e.Graphics.DrawString(textBox10.Text.ToString(), new Font("BroadWay", 18, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, 634, 144);
    e.Graphics.DrawString(textBox11.Text.ToString(), new Font("BroadWay", 18, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, 634, 215);
    e.Graphics.DrawString(textBox12.Text.ToString(), new Font("BroadWay", 18, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, 634, 266);
    e.Graphics.DrawString(textBox13.Text.ToString(), new Font("BroadWay", 18, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, 238, 382);
    e.Graphics.DrawString(textBox14.Text.ToString(), new Font("BroadWay", 12, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, 388, 421);

    }
```

The code is working great but only i want now to print it in dot matrix font
 that not yet done . i hope one of you will help me 
my printer is LX-300+ II Impact Printer
i have no idea what to do now!

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience with arabic (or whatever that language is) but, simply setting the font to "Courier New" usually solves that problem. You might have to convert text encoding to ansi from unicode.